# Set dynamic button width depending on the ElevatedButton text length

Tags: flutter, dart

How can I set dynamic button `width` depending on the `ElevatedButton` text length?

```dart
Container(
  height: 36.0,
  //width: 127,
  child: ElevatedButton(
    onPressed: () {},
    child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Icon(Icons.power_settings_new_outlined),
          Text("Login",),
        ]
    ),
  ),
),
```

What I would like to achieve is this:

[image: Login]

[image: Login Long Text]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, `Row` has its [`mainAxisSize`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Flex/mainAxisSize.html) set to `MainAxisSize.max`, which make it extends horizontally inside the button. To make it shrink its size to the required width of the children, set the `mainAxisSize` to `MainAxisSize.min`:

```dart
ElevatedButton(
  // ...
  child: Row(
    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
    // ...
  ),
)
```

Comment: Ahh, so it's not the `Container` but the `Row` widget. Thank you for the answer and the explanation!